# intermittent wifi/LAN client connection issues with dhcpd and bind9 on ubuntu server

Tags: local-area-network, dhcp-server

I have a soho LAN with a gateway server running `isc-dhcpd-server` and `bind9` on one NIC 192.168.0.3 for the LAN & wifi.

The client connects to the LAN but often can't see the server on 192.168.0.3 even to ping it.

I can see the client sets up its IP address with DHCP and on some clients e.g. the mac laptop, `/etc/resolv.conf` contains the correct `name-server 192.168.0.3` entry.

On my linux laptop, when it's not connecting, the `resolv.conf` entry is not correct.

At some point from a minute to 30 mins later, the client will suddenly connect and for a while all will be fine.

Meanwhile the internet connection on the gateway server is consistently OK.

Here's the server's dhcpd.conf:

```
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.4 192.168.0.250;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option domain-search "localdomain";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.3;
  option routers 192.168.0.3;
}

log-facility local7;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
option domain-name "localdomain";
option domain-name-servers gondolin.localdomain;
ddns-updates on;
ignore client-updates;
update-static-leases on;
ddns-update-style standard;
update-optimization off;

include "/etc/dhcp/ddns-keys/rndc.key";
# must be same as "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

zone localdomain. {
     primary 192.168.0.3;
     key "rndc-key";
}

zone 0.168.192.in-addr.arpa. {
     primary 192.168.0.3;
     key "rndc-key";
}
```

`gondolin.localdomain` is the gateway hostname.

I'm not getting any errors in `/var/log/dhcpd.log` and the lease entries in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases` look like this:

```
lease 192.168.0.233 {
  starts 0 2019/11/03 18:00:35;
  ends 0 2019/11/03 20:00:35;
  cltt 0 2019/11/03 18:00:35;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet 24:5b:a7:20:26:a2;
  uid "\001$[\247 &\242";
  set ddns-rev-name = "233.0.168.192.in-addr.arpa.";
  set ddns-dhcid = "\000\001\001x\341c*8-]\267\336\210;3d$\376#\203\273P\207\002\375=\3327\035[\241\307\262\374/";
  set ddns-fwd-name = "Sylvies-iPhone.localdomain";
  client-hostname "Sylvies-iPhone";
}
```

I can't find any errors on the gateway server, nor on the clients in  ubuntu `/var/log/syslog` or iOS `/var/log/system.log` files.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just the wifi access point. I did a power cycle and it was all fine.